# SBCL on Vista crashes. Do you know how to make it work?

Tags: windows-vista, lisp, crash, sbcl

I've searched a lot for an answer for this question in the web: they say it's true, SBCL doesn't work under Vista.
But I really need to work with lisp on my home Vista laptop and VM doesn't help really...
And CL is not so interesting because of speed...

If you have any recommendation, please share!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you seen these articles?

http://robert.zubek.net/blog/2008/04/09/sbcl-emacs-windows-vista/

http://brainrack.wordpress.com/2008/05/29/running-sbcl-on-windows/

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have DEP off for SBCL.

Comment: Can you be a little bit more specific?

Comment: If you have Vista configured such that DEP (data execution prevention) is on for all processes, SBCL may crash upon start.  If this is the case, turning DEP off for SBCL should cause it to work.  (DEP can be configured under the performance options in the advanced system setting in Vista).